# How to initialize a windows disk in .Net Core

Tags: azure, .net-core

I am setting up an Azure VM using a .Net Core exe (turning on MSDTC, making sure all the features are installed, etc). The VM will have attached drives that have not been initialized yet. In Powershell I can simply use `Initialize-Disk -PartitionStyle MBR` and then `New-Partition -UseMaximumSize -DriveLetter 'D'` to create the partition.

How do I initialize the disk and create a partition in C# Core?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the below namespaces.

`Microsoft.Azure.Management.ResourceManager.Fluent Microsoft.Azure.Management.Compute.Fluent.Models`

```
        var Auth_credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromFile(@"C:\Tools\azureauth.properties");

        var az = Azure
            .Configure()
            .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
            .Authenticate(Auth_credentials)
            .WithDefaultSubscription();

        var virtualMachine = az.VirtualMachines.GetByResourceGroup("resourceGroupName", "vmName");
        Console.WriteLine(virtualMachine.Name);

        DataDisk disc = new DataDisk(virtualMachine.StorageProfile.DataDisks.Count + 1, DiskCreateOptionTypes.Empty, null, 15, null);
        disc.Validate();
        virtualMachine.StorageProfile.DataDisks.Add(disc);
        virtualMachine.StorageProfile.Validate();
        virtualMachine.Update().Apply();
```

[image]

For further information, refer to the SO [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54762062/discutils-create-an-ntfs-vhd) and SO [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54644466/how-to-create-simple-volume-from-unallocated-partition).

Comment: That will add a disk to an Azure VM. I want to initialize the disk. Once I add the disk it is now an uninitialized disk on the VM. I'm running code to setup the VM and I need to initialize the disk after adding it to the machine.